# ReactiveAsyncCommand missing in ReactiveUI 5.0.2

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, c#-5.0, reactiveui

I just start learn ReactiveUI from https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples/blob/master/ReactiveUI_4Only.Samples.sln.

I download lastest version via nuget but I cant find class ReactiveAsyncCommand  in ReactiveUI.Xaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ReactiveAsyncCommand`](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI/Legacy/ReactiveAsyncCommand.cs) is now in `ReactiveUI.Legacy`.

Comment: May I ask why is that? I'm not familiar with Rx but I plan to get into it as soon as I have some time to.

Comment: @HighCore I'm not sure why that is that way.  ReactiveUI is different than Rx, though...

Comment: @Reed: Thank you, it is my first day with reactiveUI, so I was confuse :)

Comment: If you're using RxUI 5.0, just use ReactiveCommand, they are now merged and have a better API.

Comment: @PaulBetts So is there anything that needs to be done to make ReactiveCommand have Async behavior like changing some property ?

Comment: No property, just call RegisterAsync and friends