# ReactiveUI 5 instant search

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, system.reactive, reactiveui

Following my earlier question about [Reactive Extensions Instant Search for WPF/MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168500/reactive-extensions-instant-search-for-wpf-mvvm), wherein...

> I would like to implement a TextBox where, as you type, results appear instantly in another ListBox

...I found that this problem had originally been addressed by [ReactiveUI](http://www.reactiveui.net/) and there was a [relatively straightforward solution](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2010/07/05/reactivexaml-series-implementing-search-with-observableaspropertyhelper/) posted in the ReactiveUI blog and documentation.

Fast forward to ReactiveUI 5, and the API has been changed, and the old examples don't work any more. [ReactiveAsyncCommand has been merged with ReactiveCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792826/reactiveasynccommand-missing-in-reactiveui-5-0-2); however ReactiveCommand doesn't seem to have a `RegisterAsyncFunction()` method necessary to get things working.

Unfortunately the ReactiveUI documentation is very much out of date. How can I get this sample working with the new API?

Comment: There is some documentation here https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/tree/docs/docs/basics

Some of it is related to the ReactiveCommand. It goes into detail of the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're using ReactiveUI 5.x? `RegisterAsyncFunction` definitely still exists, here's where it is:

https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI/ReactiveCommand.cs#L273

Comment: ReactiveUI 5.5.1, installed via NuGet. My bad, actually - I was assigning my ReactiveCommand to a member variable of type ICommand, so obviously extension methods of ReactiveCommand did not apply.

Comment: link is dead :(

Comment: I sure hope it's dead, ReactiveUI 5.x is super dead :P  The modern equivalent is `ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask`